# Watin :select item from dropdown list, its values are populated from another dropdown list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, nunit, watin

I'm new to Watin, and and I'm using to automate site use jave and iface technology, 
I'm trying to select from drop-down list, its values are populated from another dropdownlist and I'm using the latest WatiN release and am doing a C# unit test in VS2008. I've coded:

```
browser.SelectList(Find.ById("BillEnrollmentForm:selectedIndustry")).Option("Charity").Select();

 browser.SelectList(Find.ById("onlinePayment:panelTabSet1:0:quickPaymentTable:0:selectedBiller")).option("Resala").Select();
```

it executed the first one and selected from the drop-down list , but when it comes to the second one , it takes too much time and displays this exception

```
"WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException : Timeout while Internet Explorer busy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this between the commands

```
browser.WaitForComplete();
```

if it not helps increase the watin timeout when you initializing the browser

```
Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut = 240; //in seconds
Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut = 240;
```

Comment: Thank you for supporting,I used the method SelectNoWait() instead of Select() and it works and selects from the drop-down the correct value but when I view the page I found that the Drop-down returns to the default value again what I should do

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the items the following way:

```
browser.SelectList(Find.ById("BillEnrollmentForm:selectedIndustry")).Select("Charity");
browser.SelectList(Find.ById("onlinePayment:panelTabSet1:0:quickPaymentTable:0:selectedBiller")).Select("Resala");
```

Also you can try to verify that the second drop-down exist ( I think there's something very wrong with the id )

Comment: I tried it but it isn't working here is apiece of the html code      <select onblur="setFocus('');" id="onlinePayment:panelTabSet1:0:quickPaymentTable:0:selectedBiller" onchange="setFocus('');Ice.selectChange(form,this,event,300);" class="iceSelOneMnu mediumInput" onfocus="setFocus(this.id);" size="1" name="onlinePayment:panelTabSet1:0:quickPaymentTable:0:selectedBiller"><option selected="selected" value="All">All</option>
<option value="23">ESDP</option>
<option value="37">Resala</option>

Comment: How :) You can post a reply yourself with the solution so other can benefit from that

Comment: I have another question, I'd be grateful if you have an answer for it at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623145/watinhow-to-handle-click-link-that-opens-icefaces-popup

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by using SelectNoWait() method .

```
  browser.SelectList(Find.ById("onlinePayment:panelTabSet1:0:quickPaymentTable:0:selectedIndustry")).Option("Phone").SelectNoWait();
  Thread.Sleep(10000);
```